# Saving pictures in IPhone apps

Tags: ios, uiimage, nskeyedarchiver

I have an app with array of objects, which i archived and unarchived

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    title = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Title"];
    image = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Image"];
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"Title"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:image forKey:@"Image"];
}
```

will `UIImage` store okay in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coder and Decoder , which was implement in the question are OK

Comment: Have you tried it in iOS 4.3? It looks like Apple may have added NSCoding support to UIImage in iOS5, but it wasn't there in iOS4, so I bet it crashes if you run it in the 4.3 simulator, in which case you'll still need to use my solution unless you're only targeting 5.0 upwards.

Comment: What happens when you try it on iOS5?

Comment: And you definitely used the same key names for loading and saving? Does you solution work on IOS4 by the way?

Answer (score 3):

No, UIImage doesn't conform to the NSCoding protocol.

To save an image, convert it to NSData using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, quality)` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` and then you can save the NSData object in your coder because it does conform to NSCoding.

Like this:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if ((self = [super init])){
        title = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Title"];
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"ImageData"]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    [aCoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"Title"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) forKey:@"ImageData"];
}
```

PS, I assume you're using ARC? If you aren't you'll need to retain the values in your initWithCoder method because `decodeObjectForKey:` returns an autoreleased object. I've also rewritten your initWithCoder to include the normal super/nil check, which is best practice.

Note that you may wish to use `self = [self init]` or `self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]` instead of `self = [super init]`, depending on what your superclass is and whether your init does any additional setup.

Comment: A user can add jpeg or png, we dont know. will it work okay if my image is in JPEG? or how should i implement encodeWithCoder?

Comment: PNG is lossless so it can be used to save JPEGs without any quality loss, but the images will be bigger than they need to be. I you know the file type you can save using UIImageJpegRepresentation instead.

Comment: i cant check it now. because the gallery in the simulator is empty. do you why? where should i save pictures for using them in the simulator?

Comment: Just drag an image onto the simulator window/phone and it will open in Mobile Safari. Then hold-click on it until the "Save Image" action sheet comes up. Save it and it will appear in your photo library.